# I can't figure out how to write correct table for lua to pass already known information for next set of locales

Tags: lua, lua-table, grand-theft-auto

I want to pass already known information in Lua from one table down to next locales, but somehow, I am still receiving "attempt to index nil value". It's probably silly and easy to fix, but I am not a programmer and I learn as I go.

```
for k,v in pairs(FoundObjects)do

            if v.HashIs == vehhash then
                print ("Found Model Name: " .. v.ModNam)  -- v.ModNam is known and correct - I want to pass this information down below as "modelName" value
            local   modelName = v.ModNam

            local ped = GetPlayerPed(-1)
            local vehicle = GetVehiclePedIsIn(ped, false)
            local vehhash   = GetEntityModel(vehicle)
            local GetHandling = GetVehicleHandlingFloat(vehicle, "CHandlingData", "fInitialDragCoeff")
            local currentEngineMod = GetVehicleMod(vehicle, 11)

            originalfInitialDragCoeff = Config.modelName.fInitialDragCoeff   -- when written name of the car instead of "modelName", passing of the value from config file works!
            originalfDriveBiasFront =   Config.modelName.fDriveBiasFront
            originalfSteeringLock = Config.modelName.fSteeringLock
            originalfTractionCurveMax = Config.modelName.fTractionCurveMax
            originalfTractionCurveMin = Config.modelName.fTractionCurveMin
            originalfTractionCurveLateral = Config.modelName.fTractionCurveLateral
            originalfLowSpeedTractionLossMult = Config.modelName.fLowSpeedTractionLossMult

print(modelName)    -- actually prints the value needed!
print(originalfInitialDragCoeff) -- unfortunately, this shows as a Nil
```

- vehhash - is numerable value given by a vehicle my game character is in
- v.ModNam - is correctly transforming vehhash from number to name of the car needed
- modelName - unfortunately, modelName doesn't share the actual car name and throws at me "attempt to index nil value"

originalfInitialDragCoeff = Config.modelName.fInitialDragCoeff

- when instead of "modelName" I am gonna write the actual car name, everything works perfectly, but I need the script to do the check in which car player always is, obviously.

Comment: If you could, could you please provide a partial table of `FoundObjects`? I don't see anything inherently wrong here yet, but it could be in the table itself. Additionally, is it even printing: `Found Model Name: <model name>`?

Comment: As a side note, it occurs to me you're using `pairs` for your iteration. If `FoundObjects` is akin to `FoundObjects = {{HashIs = 12345, ModName = "Ford" ...}, {HashIs = 42424, ModName = "Chevy" ...}}`, then you probably want to use `ipairs`.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that you're using dot notation for your variable in a table. You cannot use dot notation if it's a variable. Instead, you need to use `Config[modelName].fInitialDragCoeff`, for example.